# Linux/Ubuntu bridge causes tcp retransmission and DUP ACK

Tags: linux-networking, bridge, ubuntu-16.04, interface, bridged-adapter

When I do configure a network bridge on my Ubuntu server I got each packet to be retransmitted and getting many duplicate ACKs...
[as this wireshark image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuNmQ.png)

my bridge interface config is:

```
iface enp5s0 inet manual


auto br0
iface br0 inet static
      address 172.25.25.1
      netmask 255.255.255.0
      network 172.25.25.0
      gateway 172.25.25.251
      broadcast 172.25.25.255
      dns-nameservers 172.25.25.251
      bridge_ports enp5s0
      bridge_stp off
      bridge_fd 0
      bridge_maxwait 0
```

Kernel: Linux 4.13.0-38-generic #43~16.04.1-Ubuntu x86_64
OS: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

my ethtool results:

```
ethtool enp5s0
Settings for enp5s0:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 1
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: on
    Supports Wake-on: g
    Wake-on: g
    Link detected: yes
```

also I do set

```
sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=0
```

Do I miss any thing? or is it a bug somewhere ? or there is a something messy!

I have tried the hwe kernel 4.13 and the generic 4.4
tried to change the switch/cables .. all the same, just removing the bridge interface and add the ip directly solves the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No issue with the network bridge... and the problem was with the `tcpdump -i any`. It captured each packet twice! One at the `br0` and the other on the physical interface itself.